# Where can I best farm Mutagen Samples?

Tags: warframe

I need a lot of Mutagen Samples to do Infested research in my clan dojo.  I know that Mutagen samples drop on Eris missions and Orokin derelict missions.  Is there a specific mission within these locations or other game method/mechanic to easily acquire more Mutagen Samples?  I am not looking to spend platinum to accomplish this.

Comment: Funny thing about Mutagen samples are I never really figured out how to farm for them, and had to rely on alerts to get Mutagen Masses until I played my first ODD.  Got nearly 400 in a few waves, but now I have so many I don't really need them anymore

Comment: I can get the Masses no problem through war events, but the actual Samples are needed for crafting blueprints.  And after looking at the wiki, the drop locations shuffled around a bit since the last time I put any effort into the game, so as of now (Patch 15 era) It's Eris and Derelicts.

Comment: Yeah, ODD works extremely well for this, and so will Dark Sector Defense. In general, any defense mission on Eris or ODD will work the best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two ways to get Mutagen Samples, according the to [WF Wikia:](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mutagen_Sample)

- Eris
- Orokin Derelict

For **Eris**, I would pick the following nodes:

- Akkad (*Dark Sector Defense*)
- Zabala (*Dark Sector Survival*)

I would advise playing on a Dark Sector Defense or Dark Sector Survival the spawns are plentiful and mutagen samples will be easy to come by. However, since the Dark Sectors are clan owned, if the tax rates are too high, especially on resources, go to the Derelict.

For the **Orokin Derelict**, any mission works:

- Survival
- Sabotage
- Defense
- Exterminate

The easiest way by far will be to run a Defense, as you can sit in one spot, avoid relatively little harm (just watch out for the Mutalist Tar Ospreys), fire in one general area without moving around, and easily farm samples this way.

Loadout-wise, bring a Nekros with you for extra loot chance and a Vauban to gather up the loot in one place. A properly placed Vortex along with a Nekros can net you plentiful amounts of mutagen samples without the risk of going down, say in a survival or an exterminate.

Comment: I'll load up an Ignis with gas damage and grab some friends to give this a shot.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I would advise not bringing an Ignis to Eris or ODD, unless you have it properly forma'd and such. The DPS output is extremely low and it sucks up ammo so quickly. I personally forma'd the Torid for use in any defense mission, so for Infested I have a Viral and Heat build that procs nearly every microsecond, and since the Torid has a bubble and a duration time you can just pop them on the pod and watch the Infested crumble.

Comment: I will give you that, it is not as effective, but it is a personal preference because I enjoy setting hideously deformed abominations that consume and corrupt flesh ablaze or eradicated through toxic gas.  (Rifle ammo mutation helps).  I do thank you for offering optimization solutions, they are helpful for when I want to be serious about farming.

Comment: @MadMAxJr So did these tips work out for you?

Comment: Ogris is really nice on the ODD if you upgrade the damage a bit. It can reach massive AoE damage, and with a Vaubon, can wreck.